# Probability of death for individual in group

Tags: probability

I was never good with probability. I have this question which is not a homework. Let's say we have a set of $N$ people. Each has a probability $p$ to die at a given moment. What is the probability that a given person $x$  from the set of $N$ people dies before the remaining $N-1$ persons?

I am not sure where to start? In fact I am not sure $N$ plays a roll here?
Thanks.

Note: Death can occur at any moment.

Comment: Does death "check every 5 seconds, whether someone's time has come", or can people die at any moment (in a "continuum of moments")?

Comment: in a "continuum of moments"...like real life :)

Comment: Then I don't think that "checking at each point in a continuum" is a good mathematical model. What comes to mind is, for example, the exponential distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution; for the waiting time until an event occurs). But realistically, the probability that two people die at the exact same time is $ 0 $, so someone is bound to die before everyone else. Because of symmetry, for any person involved, the probability of being the "winner" of this race is $ \frac{1}{N} $. Unless you meant that different people have different $p$'s.

Comment: @nasekatnasushi, It is questionable if N is relevant, as long as $N>=2$, so $P($x$_dies_before_$y$)$, $N=2$ is no different than if N=3 for example. Accordingly $1/N$ may not be correct in this case.

Comment: You say in the comments that there is a "continuum of moments". This suggests that the probability that a given person dies at a given moment is $0$. That is $p=0$. So that leaves the question: What is the distribution of death times? Having said that, I agree with nasekatnasushi, that if everyone has the same death distribution, then the probability that any specific person is the first to die is $\frac1N$. Regarding the subsequent comment of NoChance: the events of various people dying before various other people are not independent.

Comment: It sounds like that probability is$ \frac1N$. If someone dies before all $N-1$ people, it means they die first. If all people have probability $p$ of dying in a given moment, no one is more or less likely to die in a given moment (probabilities are equal).